# symfony swiftmailer: mail not sent in prod-environment

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

I have a symfony 2.8 app, with fosuserbundle implemented. In the `dev` environment, the registration confirm mails are sent, but not in the `prod` environment. There is no log message and the smpt configuration is correct.

sf version: 2.8.1
swiftmailer-bundle version: current (compatible with sf version; `2.*` in composer json)
fosuserbundle: 1.3.5 (`*` in composer)

dev-config:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
    #strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: true }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true

assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

Has anyone the same problem?

**edit**

I just tried a mail with the following console command in `prod` env: `php sf --env=prod swiftmailer:email:send`

Terminal output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
From: test@antondachauer.de
To: mail@antondachauer.de
Subject: test
Body: test
Sent 1 emails
```

But the mail has not been sent. In the `dev` env, it works also in terminal.

Comment: Is the prod environment on the same server?  Have you changed any of the standard configuration settings for Swiftmailer, and/or are you coming from a fresh 2.8.1 install or is this upgraded from a previous version?  What OS are you using?

Comment: The prod environment ist on the same server (Ubuntu 14.04). I've updated from 2.3.x and I use the default swiftmailer configuration

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache ?

Comment: What is the configuration of `swiftmailer` in `config*.yml` files? Does it use spool? How is it linked to FOSUserBundle? Are all email never sent or only emails from FOSUserBundle?

Comment: taking a look at `app/logs/prod.log` could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions mentioned [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/373/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-173-194-205-108-0),
which is "gethostbyname" and "change smtp of Gmail" but it did not work.

After a few days of digging, I found a solution, you need to change the encryption to tls, and add ssl in stream_options in config. It's not recommended according to the security standpoint, but it works in my case.

#### parameters.yml

```
mailer_prod_encryption: tls
```

#### config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
  transport:  "%mailer_dev_transport%"
  host:       "%mailer_dev_host%"
  username:   "%mailer_dev_user%"
  password:   "%mailer_dev_password%"
  encryption: "%mailer_dev_encryption%"
  auth_mode:  "%mailer_dev_auth_mode%"
  spool:     { type: memory }
  port: 25
  stream_options:
    ssl:
      allow_self_signed: true
      verify_peer: false
```